# How to get useID/Email of logged in user in Google Contacts API after OauTh Token

Tags: api

I developed a program which works well and I can import data from gmail but. I want to keep track how is the user given permission to manage contacts. But after a hard search I did not get any Idea about the loged in user. My code is as follows.

============================================

```
var parameters = new OAuth2Parameters
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"].ToString(),
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"].ToString(),
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectURL"].ToString(),
                Scope ="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"

            };

            parameters.AccessCode = Request.QueryString["Code"].ToString();
            OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
            Session["Token"] = parameters.AccessToken;
```

==================================

But I dont how to get email of logged in user. Please let me that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Request an additionall scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email and then you can access the user info as well. There is also a userinfo.profile witch contains other info on the user like name, profile picture, language and so on.

Your code looks like C# but I only have a Python example of using multiple scopes and sharing tokens.

Code: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-oauth-demo/
Article: http://www.hackviking.com/2013/10/python-get-user-info-after-oauth/